# What prevents an ip_forwarded-enabled server to be used by an attacker as a router

Tags: linux, security, routing, ip-forwarding

### Setup / Question

Given a server on the public internet with the IP `185.48.117.176` with `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward=1` and no iptable-rules.

What prevents an attacker that is

1. directly or
2. indirectly (through another router)

connected to the internet from using my server as her router?

(I know, without proper masquerading set up its useless as the reposonses would not be routed back, however it could still be used for UDP flooding attacks where the response package isn't expected anyway.)

### What I tried:

I tried to add a route (on my client/attacker machine)

```
route add 0.0.0.0 gw 185.48.117.176
```

after I added a "fake interface ip"

```
ip address add dev wlan0 scope link 185.48.117.176
```

to prevent the `SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable` error message.
I then deleted the "fake interface ip" so the route stays.

However I am still not able to use the server as a route, as no packages arrive there (I tried to capture ICMP packages using tcpdump).

As of [this post](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14041#issuecomment-223467379) on a docker issue, it seems to be related to whether the network supports layer 2 switching.

Why is this? What am I missing?

Comment: If you have no interface in the same network as the 185.48.117.176 gateway then you cannot use it as a next-hop or default gateway.

Comment: Why? What is technically preventing me from doing that?

Comment: @GameScripting, how do you expect your client machine to reach 185.48.117.176 ?  Your *default gateway* should be a *locally reachable* address which allows you to connect to non-local IP nodes.

Comment: ARP. Your device will send an ARP request (broadcast), trying to get the Layer 2 MAC address associated with 185.48.117.176. Because no interfaces are physically connected to 185.48.117.176, no ARP reply will come back.

Answer (score 0):

From [@MarkoPolo (comments)](https://serverfault.com/questions/798395/what-prevents-an-ip-forwarded-enabled-server-to-be-used-by-an-attacker-as-a-rout?noredirect=1#comment1011266_798395):

> Your device will send an ARP request (broadcast), trying to get the Layer 2 MAC address associated with 185.48.117.176. Because no interfaces are physically connected to 185.48.117.176, no ARP reply will come back

And to pysically reach your target (`185.48.117.176`) you need to send package to a device pysically connected to `185.48.117.176` to a device physically connected to that and so on.

In therory you could for example build up a ethernet package with a fake MAC adress of your router (to answer case `2. indirectly (through another router)`) and it would foward the package into the public net, which is ok, because thats how routing works.

What net are you trying to reach/inject a package into?

- If it was any of the RFC 1918 address, no public router will route it, because where should such a private network be?
- If it was a public net, it is public reachable anyway

So it only makes sense to try to inject a package into a private net if you are physically connected to the router physically connected to the private net.
And beeing physically connected was out of question, you then of course need proper filtering.

---

**EDIT:**

Keep in mind:
If the attacker is your ISP / controls devices from the ISP, connected to the router/datacenter one is able to get packages into your network. If you have NAT enabled one can communicate with the devices in the private net.

If that is a case for you keep in mind to set up proper filtering.

Answer (score 0):

A packet cannot be addressed both to that machine and to the victim. If addressed to the victim, it will not go to that machine. If addressed to that machine, it will not be forwarded because it has reached its destination.

Strictly speaking, a packet can be addressed to go to a machine and then on to a destination -- this is called [source routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_routing). But such requests are not honored unless the machine is badly misconfigured.